# i'm stuck when I'm trying to make two primary key's in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i have a class attendance like

```
public class Attendance  implements Serializable
{
    private Integer id,userId;
    private Date date;
    private  OfficeTime officeTime;
    private Set<TimeSlice> timeSlices;
    public Attendance()
    {

    }
}
```

now i'm try to make two primary key's using hibernate mapping composite-id

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
          <class name="Attendance">
           <composite-id>
              <key-property name="id"><generator class="increment"/></key-property>
              <key-property name="date" />
          </composite-id>

          <property name="userId" />

          <set name="timeSlices" cascade="all" >
            <key column="attendanceId" />
            <one-to-many class="TimeSlice" />
          </set>

          <many-to-one name="officeTime" class="OfficeTime"
            column="office_id" unique="true" not-null="true"
            cascade="all" />

          </class>

          </hibernate-mapping>
```

while am doing like this i got error The content of element type "key-property" must match "(meta*,column*,type?)".
how to set two primary key's and one must be increment automatically.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have only one primary key.

Comment: Have you seen this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284175/how-to-make-two-column-as-a-primary-key-in-hibernate-annotation-class`

Comment: How do you want to have two "first" elements?

Comment: i need only  one object for a day

Comment: Hari: the point is: a "primary" key (primary, being the "first" element), is unique. You can create keys based on more than one column, but you can not have more than one primary key in one table.

Comment: Your ID column is based on generated serial number. Therefore, it is unique already, and you don't need a composite key. And of course, a composite key is not the same as having two keys.

Comment: @Stultuske actually what i need is one key i.e id should be unique and another one i.e date is also be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration is not following the schema that is set for the composite-id element. 
Here is the schema doc for the composite id:

```
<composite-id name="propertyName" class="ClassName" mapped="true|false" access="field|property|ClassName"> node="element-name|." <key-property name="propertyName" type="typename" column="column_name"/> <key-many-to-one name="propertyName class="ClassName" column="column_name"/> ...... </composite-id>
```

This is a sample configuration:

```
<composite-id>
            <key-many-to-one name="username" class="org.myclass.UserDB" column="user_name"/>
            <key-property name="role" type="string" column="role_name"/>
        </composite-id>
```

The documentation for this is here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid